# Generating XSD schemas for .NET classes

Tags: .net, xml, xsd

I have a set of classes which hold only data (no operations have been defined in this class). How do i generate a xsd file for these classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xsd Assembly.dll
```

Type `xsd /?` for all the options, you can specify specific types as well.

UPDATE:

A better option will be to design a proper schema and use `xsd /c myschema.xsd` to generate to proper classes for you  :)